How to define Directory structure Using StandardDirectory in WiX v5 (Equivalent to v3 Directory Hierarchy)

<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">

    <Directory Id="MyApplication" Name="My Application">

        <Directory Id="Bin" Name="bin" />

        <Directory Id="Config" Name="config" />

        <Directory Id="Logs" Name="logs" />

    </Directory>

</Directory>

In WiXv5 there is a shift from Directory element to using StandardDirectory atleast as a Parent. I'd like to know how to use this StandardDirectory element while maintaining the same Directory Hierarchy

Change the first Directory element to StandardDirectory (and matching close element). That's it.
